# InfoPath: Compare if any value in Person Picker matches current logged in user

Tags: infopath, infopath-rules

In InfoPath 2013 form, I am able to match for a single value in the people picker with current logged in user using formula rule-

```
AccountId = userName()
```

But in case if we have multiple users in `AccountId` then how to match if any of these users matches `userName()`

**EDIT 1**

If I set the People Picker to accept multiple names and then use

```
contains(AccountId, username())
```

It matches the username's substring also. Meaning if I enter `user` but current user is `user_1`, the condition is true.

Comment: Have you checked result of multiple users? I mean how it will display multiple users with (;) or (,)?

Comment: In People Picker it shows with (;).

Answer (score 1):

For a multiple selection enabled People Picker field, you should be able to match current user using the **contains** function in the formula shown below

```
contains(AccountId, userName())
```

In this case if the Account ID contains the current user's login name, the formula would return true and false otherwise.

Comment: This fails if I have username like - `user` and `user_1`. Now if it is `user` then condition is also true for `user_1`

Answer (score 0):

`Concat` username with `;`. and check it with contains condition. It must be give false if verifying `user` with including `user_1` also.

Comment: There is another problem now. After specifying multiple users in People Picker, if we look at the value of its AccountId you'll see only first user.

Comment: Have you checked account id display as repeating section in data source? like having any groups on account id?

Comment: No, AccountId is simple field of PeoplePicker

Comment: Please try to get data in other control (Dropdown, Multi selection, textarea) except textbox control.

Comment: Does InfoPath Rules allow us to do that?

Comment: Yes, try it just for check why all users are not displaying.